# Does anyone actually die?

Tags: naruto

I've started watching *Naruto* and was wondering if anyone actually dies or if it is like *Dragon Ball* and it never really happens.

Please no spoilers about who dies, just if someone does or if there are serious injuries inflicted.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, people die.  The first major arc (Zabuza arc) features multiple deaths. Several villains die throughout the story.  Some country leaders also die, as do some fairly plot-important characters and/or their relatives.  A lot of the most important characters end up near-death, but survive for various reasons.  Not all of those are able to recover well enough to resume their previous lives.

> Some of the dead ones don't stay dead, though.  Some of those come back as zombies.  But then they go back to being dead.  Others just get a resurrection spell cast on them.  Kind of like in Dragon Ball.

Comment: Dude, seriously?! That's one of the biggest spoilers.

Comment: TMI for a question specifically asks for no spoilers, Thus I completely agree with Alchemist

Answer (score 3):

There are often serious injuries inflicted on "good guys" which causes them to be assumed dead but they usually end up alive and well with a few exceptions here and there.

> There is a medical ninja who basically magically cures everyone.

The villains die more often but some of the stronger ones live and cause a lot of trouble. Most just die though.

Comment: You can put spoilers in a dedicated spoiler-tag, by starting the line with ">!". That way, people can decide themselves whether they want to see the spoiler. I did it for you now, but this is how you are supposed to mark spoilers in the future. Anyway, welcome to the Anime & Manga Stackexchange. I hope you enjoy it here :)